# How can I copy an AMI between regions in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami, debian-lenny

We are having difficulty copying an AMI we have created in our California VPC to our Oregon VPC as the AKI and ARI are not available in Oregon.

The AKI/ARI we are using in California are as follows.

aki-f70657b2
ari-ff0657ba

When I try and copy the instance it fails with the error message "Matching for ari ari-ff0657ba not found in the destination region".

The instance is a 32-bit version of Debian Lenny and I haven't had any luck getting it to boot in Oregon using the existing Kernels in that region. Is there any way the AKI/ARI can be copied from California to Oregon and if this isn't possible what options do I have?

I actually copied the snapshot over to Oregon and then created an image from the snapshot however the pv-grub AKI's available there wont boot the instance and  and i am presented with a grub prompt.

Any ideas on how I can get Debian Lenny working in Oregon? I have several bare metal lenny machines, would it be possible to build an image from one of them using the amazon toolkit and then upload it maybe?

Really not sure on the best approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Debian Lenny is very old and I assume that's the reason why Oregon doesn't provide the kernels you need to run your image. The only thing I can think of is to update your PV-Grub and create new AMIs. Maybe this helps: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html

If you don't find matching AKI in the other region there is no way afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Try **copy-image** command for that

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/appstream/copy-image.html?highlight=image